# Iframe does not load all its styles in production

Tags: javascript, webpack

Currently Im working on a chat widget using webpack but am facing a strange issue where the iframe does not load all it's styles in production, works fine on local. For example

```
const ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');

ifrm.style.position = "absolute";
ifrm.style.width = "65";
ifrm.style.height = "65";
ifrm.style.border = "none";
ifrm.style.zIndex = '9999998';
ifrm.style.background = "transparent";
ifrm.style.right = "0";
ifrm.style.bottom = "0";
ifrm.style.margin = "40 50";
```

loads only this in production:

```
style="position: absolute; border: none; 
z-index: 9999998; background: transparent; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"
```

As you can see, it completely forgets width, height and margin

Any ideas whats going on? This happens on both firefox and chrome

Comment: Those values lack the units, units are not optional.

Comment: @Teemu Derp you are correct, not sure why it was working fine in local

Comment: Most likely it isn't, you've a cache issue or something.